# How to save the shell wget link to download the file name

Tags: linux, shell, wget

For example: wget http://api.np.mobilem.360.cn/redirect/down/?from=zdian_api&appid=5576 After downloading, I want to use a variable abc save the download link in this file name, and how it should achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this.

```
abc=$(wget -qO - http://api.no.mobilem....)
```

It saves the output of the `wget` in a shell variable called `abc`.

Then you can do

```
echo $abc
```